# iOS iCloud initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

I use this code to initialize iCloud access (I've got it from an [Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloud101/CodeListings/CodeListings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011317-CH8-SW1))

```
- (void)initializeiCloudAccess {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
        if (ubiq)
            NSLog(@"iCloud is available.\n");
        else
            NSLog(@"iCloud is not available.\n");
    });
}
```

But I receive `NSInvalidArgumentException` with reason `unrecognized selector sent to instance ...` when I try to get `ubiq`;

Can anyone explain to me what's the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your project is configured to use the latest iOS SDK (at least 5.0 to use iCloud) and that your device or simulator has iOS 5 or greater. If you need to target previous versions of iOS as well, you need a condition before sending the message:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore")) { 
   // iCloud API available, safe to send URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier message
   ...
}
```

Comment: You mean, I can't use iCloud if version of my iOS SDK < 5.0?

Comment: @flamingo No, you can't. iCloud appeared for the first time in iOS 5.0. Ref: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4759